# Selenium on getting span innerhtml

Tags: c#, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<div id="ctl00_cphRoblox_rbxGroupFundsPane_GroupFunds" class="StandardBox" style="padding-right:0">
<b>Funds:</b> 
<span class="robux" style="margin-left:5px">128</span>
</div>
```

Ok so I want to get the 128 but sometimes it gives me "18"
and I have no idea

I tried:

```
dcWeb.SendMessage(s + " = Pending and Robux: " + driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("robux")).GetAttribute("innerHTML"));
```

and

```
dcWeb.SendMessage(s + " = Pending and Robux: " + driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("robux")).GetAttribute("textContent"));
```

Comment: Why dont u just use ".Text" instead of getAttribute

Answer (score 0):

To to get the text **128** you can use the following line of code :

```
dcWeb.SendMessage(s + " = Pending and Robux: " + driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='StandardBox' and contains(@id,'_cphRoblox_rbxGroupFundsPane_GroupFunds')]//span[@class='robux']")).GetAttribute("innerHTML"));
```